# CSS grid, centering 1 div, remaining divs on the next line

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build some sort of pyramid in a parent div.
I have 4 children divs. I want the first child to be centered. And the remaining divs underneath the first one (second row).

```
<style>
.parent {
   width: 100%;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat: (3, 1fr)
}
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

I expect to have a result that looks like this: http://prntscr.com/orr41c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i did :

```
/* first child goes in the first row / second column and span 1 column */

.parent .child:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-column: 2/ span 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    background: red;
  }

  /* the 3 other children place themselves in the second row */

  .parent .child:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    grid-row: 2;
  }
```

```html
<style>
  .parent {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat: (3, 1fr);
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .parent .child {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .parent .child:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-column: 2/ span 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    background: red;
  }
  
  .parent .child:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    grid-row: 2;
  }
</style>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does exactly what i want. Only ```grid-column: 2/ span 1;``` confuses me, i don't exactly know what each number and slash does.

Comment: Happy to help =). '2' mean position yourself on the 2nd column. '/' mean "to" as in : from here "to" there. "span 1" mean use 1 column for yourself. Another way to write it would have been : `grid-column: 2/3;` which would mean "spread from column line 2 to line 3". I have started using span as I find it easier to visualize. If you want a good visual on grid I advise you to check out your grids in Firefox inspector. In front of your grid element tag there is a "grid" button. toggle it !

Comment: The default behaviour is 'span 1' so i didn't really need to add it here (or the "/").  But this way you learned about it anyway xD. (That is also why I didn't use it for `grid-row` - a starting point was enough, the "from here" in from here to there)

Comment: It's still confusing, but with grid-column i just need to experiment in the browser to see the outcome i guess. With the '/' you basically meant 'skip a column, and start the next'?

Comment: `grid-column: 2 / 3;` is the short version of `grid-column-start: 2; grid-column-end: 3`. `span 1` just mean : `grid-column-end :` _(grid-column-start's value + 1)_. Check out [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) by CSS-Tricks, it's very well made

Answer (score -1):

Check below code. Hope this is what you expecting

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .parent {
            width: 100%;
            display: grid;
        }

        .child {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .innerTable {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .center {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="row center">
            <div>1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="innerTable">
                <div class="child">2</div>
                <div class="child">3</div>
                <div class="child">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```